# Make sure coroutine completes without cancelation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing an app that communicates through JNI with a data controller. When the main activity dies (single activity app) I wanted to clear the memory. To do that I'm using coroutines and activity's lifecycle scope with context of `Dispatchers.IO`. Is it possible (at least in theory) that activity's scope is cancelled before execution of `withContext { ...` completes? As far as I understand coroutine it is, since `withContext` is a suspend function and handles cancelation. And if this is correct, what would be preferred way of launching some cleanup code that should be executed regardless?

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStore.disconnectController()
        }
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: read [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad)

Comment: For cleanup inside a `finally` block, the best option is `withContext(nonCancellable)`. For long-running, non-cancellable work, use the other suggestions like `WorkManager` (the safest) or  `GlobalScope` (will still get killed when app goes to background)

Comment: Application scope was what I needed. Thank you guys!